# Constructing functions in R within a for loop

Tags: r, function, for-loop

I have been trouble-shooting my code, but am stuck. I am trying to run a function repeatedly in a for loop in R, while appending to a vector. My code is as follows:

```
densities = rep(NA, length(seq(0, 1, by = 0.01)))
count = 1

for (t in seq(0, 1, by = 0.01)) {
  applyThreshold(t, densities, count)
}

applyThreshold = function(t, densities, count){
  tMatrix = corMatrix
  tMatrix[corMatrix < t] = 0 
  tMatrix[corMatrix >= t] = 1
  nVector = c()
  for (n in 1:dim(tMatrix)[1]){
    nSum = sum(tMatrix[,n])
    if (nSum == 0){
      nVector = c(nVector, n)
    }
  }
  if (length(nVector) >0){
    tMatrix = tMatrix[,-(nVector)]
    tMatrix = tMatrix[-(nVector),] 
  }

  E = sum(tMatrix)/2
  V = dim(tMatrix)[1]
  densities[count] = 2*E/(V*(V-1))
  count = count + 1
}
```

At the end of running this command, though, my densities and count have not updated. I have a feeling this is a simple fix, but I have been looking at the documentation for functions in R, and am still stuck. Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: I would eliminate the first 14 lines of code in the function, set E = 2, V = 3, use seq(0, 1, by = 0.2) instead of 0.01, and post the answer you want.  Once you got that simplified function to work correctly then add the first 14 lines of code back in and try using by = 0.01.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This all sorts of screwed up.  Currently your function returns `count + 1`.  That's all it does.  You need to learn about the scope of different variables.  All those variables in your function exist only in that function when that function is called.  You need to use `return()` to get actual values back from it and store them in a separate variable.  Also, you need to make sure your function has been created before trying to use it.  If you run your code as is, applyThreshold isn't even created in your for loop.

Try running this after creating your function to see some of what I mean:

```
y <- applyThreshold(.5, densities, 5)
print(y)
```

The variable `corMatrix` doesn't even exist in your function.

Comment: I defined corMatrix earlier. Even when I add coMatrix into the explicit parameter of the function, it does not change the fact that densities and count do not change either. I don't think what you said about my function returning count+1 is correct, because it does not! If I look at count afterward, it remains the value of one. I also did try the return(c(count, densities)), but it still did not work. And, I did call the function before the for-loop even though it is written reversed. I will edit all that in. Thanks.

Comment: What I said about what it returns is correct.  Run that code snippet I told you to.

Comment: If you want count to change in your global environment you have to do that explicitly.  You don't.  You only change count in the scope of your function.  Read what I said about the variables in your function again.  If you want any of your global variables to change you need to do that explicitly.  In this case try using `<<-` in place of `=`.

Comment: Do read about variable scope in R.  There are plenty of people who ask about it.